# Does the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\sin(n+\frac 12)\pi}{1+\sqrt{n}}$ converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Does the series $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\sin(n+\frac 12)\pi}{1+\sqrt{n}}$$

This is supposed to be an alternating series but I can't seem to figure out what the $b_n$ is in this case. is there some sort of sine property I am not seeing? I'm trying to test the alternating series theorem.

Comment: What is $\sin \bigl((n+\frac{1}{2})\pi\bigr)$?

Comment: im not sure what you are asking.

Comment: If you know what that is, everything is settled. Unless you mean the term of the series is $\frac{\pi \sin (n+\frac{1}{2})}{1+\sqrt{n}}$, in which case you will need Dirichlet's criterion.

Comment: the term of the series is that.

Comment: Then I suggest moving the $\pi$ to the front, or leaving it off altogether, since it is irrelevant for convergence. If one sees $\sin (n+\frac{1}{2})\pi$, most of the time it is supposed to be parsed $\sin\bigl((n+\frac{1}{2})\pi\bigr)$.

Comment: Consider $\sin\left(n\pi+\frac12\pi\right) =\sin(n\pi)\cos\left(\frac12\pi\right) +\cos(n\pi)\sin\left(\frac12\pi\right) =0\cdot0+(-1)^n\cdot1$

Comment: This problem comes from Stewart's Calculus Early Transcendentals, 8th edition. It is problem #15 of section 11.5, Alternating Series. The way that Joshhw wrote it is the same way that it appears in the book. The pi is outside of the argument of the sine function. I'm guessing that it is an error. As others have mentioned, the pi should probably be inside of the argument of sine. The Instructor's Solution Manual for the textbook makes the same typo. Nevertheless, it shows the numerator being equivalent to (-1)^n, and says that the "series converges by the Alternating Series Test".

Answer (score 1):

$ \displaystyle \frac{\sin((n+\frac{1}{2})\pi)}{\sqrt{n}+1} = \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}+1} $

So you just have to verify that $ \displaystyle \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}+1}  $  decrease to zero...which should be kind of obvious.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why the top part is $(-1)^n$? is it because sin alternates between those two values and so you can treat it like that?

Comment: If you don't see, replace n=1,2,3,.., sin(Pi/2) = 1,sin(3Pi/2)=-1, sin(5Pi/2)=1, sin((2n+1)Pi/2) = (-1)^n ...

Comment: am I supposed to treat that pi as inside the parentheses? cause that would make this equation easier.

Comment: Please rewrite properly the problem if the pi is not inside ! But since you are talking about alternating series, it seems almost sure it's inside..otherwise it's cleary not alternate (and the Pi would be meaningless)

Comment: I never wrote it inside at all. that was the person responding. I'm trying to figure out if its supposed to be on the inside.

Comment: See above, it's clearly not outside...otherwise it has nothing to do with alternating series..but with dirichlet test (which is more difficult)

Comment: $\sin(\pi/2) = 1, \sin(3\pi/2) = -1, \sin(5\pi/2) = 1, \sin(7\pi/2) = -1$, and so on. Do you see the pattern?

Answer (score -1):

I have the book and pi goes outside, but that is no problem.
By the alternating series test, the absolute value of 
 
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin(A+%2B+B)

$\dfrac{\pi\sin(n+\dfrac{1}{2})}{1+\sqrt{n}} = \pi\dfrac{\sin(n)\cos(\dfrac{1}{2}) + \cos(n)\sin(\dfrac{1}{2})}{1+\sqrt{n}} $

is less than
$\pi\dfrac{\cos(\dfrac{1}{2}) + \sin(\dfrac{1}{2})}{1+\sqrt{n}}$, which decreases and goes to zero as n approaches infinity. 
 So, the alternating series is convergent.

In this case, we can lower the bound to $\dfrac{\pi}{1+\sqrt{n}}$ without worrying about trig identities.
We want to know whether it is conditionally or absolutely convergent. 

So we let

$S_2 = \sum\dfrac{\pi|\sin(n+\dfrac{1}{2})|}{1+\sqrt{n}}$
By the ratio test, we could compare this to $ \sum\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ and we will get a limit greater than 0. 
And we know  $ \sum\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$, thus $S_2$ diverges.

Finally your original series is CONDITIONALLY CONVERGENT.
The best way to see this is by reading chapter 11, section 11.6 (Absolute Convergence and the Ratio and Root Test) in the book "Calculus 8th edition" by James Stewart.